# How to show other content (such as an ad) after every "X" number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

I have Wordpress website and I want to implement Adsense ads into it.

I have 30 posts per page so i want to show ads after every 7 posts, how can I do this? Currently I am using this method for 3 ads in 10 posts, and after 10 posts no ads showing:

```
<center><?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 1 ) : ?>

Adsense Code Here 
<?php elseif( $wp_query->current_post == 3 ) : ?>

Adsense Code Here
<?php elseif( $wp_query->current_post == 7 ) : ?>

Adsense Code Here
<?php endif; ?></center>
```

I want to show ads after every 7 posts, is that possible in one code line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put one condition here :-

```
if( ($wp_query->current_post) % 7 == 0 ):

 Adsense Code Here

endif;
```

By this you will get 0 as reminder after every post count which is multiple of 7 like 7, 14, 21 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the modulus (or "mod") operator `%` to get the remainder of value `x` divided by value `y` i.e. `x % y = remainder`. e.g. `4 % 3 = 1` because 4 divided by 3 gives a remainder of 1.

**Your code should be:**

```
<?php if( ($wp_query->current_post % 7) == 1  ) : ?>

    Adsense Code Here

<?php endif; ?>
```

**How this works:**

You want to display the ad after **every 7 posts**, so you need to use 3 as the `y` i.e. the value to divide by. This will give the results:

```
    1st post:    1 % 7 = 1
    2nd post:    2 % 7 = 2
    3rd post:    3 % 7 = 3
    [...]
    6th post:    6 % 7 = 0
    7th post:    7 % 7 = 1
    8th post:    8 % 7 = 2
    [...]
    14th post:  14 % 7 = 1
    etc.
```

As you want to **start after the first ad**, then you want to check for a remainder value of 1.

**Tip:**

Off topic, but the `<center>` HTML tag has been deprecated so you shouldn't use it any more. use the CSS style `text-align:center` on the container element instead.