# WordPress Loop and some extra PHP to execute a code after every 4 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="forward">
    SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
</div>
```

The above is a portion of a WordPress loop. The loop is pulling posts excerpts for the front page, but what I want is this that somehow this portion should be inside a loop:

```
 <div class="forward">
        SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
    </div>
```

But with a condition that the above code should be executed after every 5 posts fetched. I am sure this should be possible with some PHP manipulation. Please help!

Comment: I think something like this should be used → for every (4n+1) some code should be executed, and n>0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show other content (such as an ad) after every "X" number of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141934/how-to-show-other-content-such-as-an-ad-after-every-x-number-of-posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this condition inside while loop and remember that 0 mean position 1, and 3 means position 4.

```
    <?php if( $my_query->current_post == 3 ) { ?>
 <div class="forward">
        SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is an example to get a good look at how it should be done:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=region&posts_per_page=5' );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    hello
    <?php if( $my_query->current_post == 3 ) { ?>
     <div class="forward">
            SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
        </div>
<?php } ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In the example above, I used `$my_query->have_posts()` in while loop so my condition would be valid.

Yours should finally look like this:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'Your Query' );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    hello
    <?php if( $my_query->current_post == 3 ) { ?>
     <div class="forward">
            SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
        </div>
<?php } ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: can't this be presented in this loop formated → `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: try this `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $my_query->while ( have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
 <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?> 
    <?php if( $my_query->current_post == 3 ) { ?>
 <div class="forward">
        SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: but will this loop work infinitely like that code will be printed after every 5th, 10th, 15th or 20th post.

Comment: by the way, this line is generating the error → `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $my_query->while ( have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the most simplest solution for your question.

```
<?php $i=0; if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $i++; ?>
    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <?php if($i % 5 == 0) : ?>
    <div class="forward">
    SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
    </div>
<?php endif; //End of the checking loop i.e multiple of 5 ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This loop work infinitely & newsletter code will execute after 5th, 10th, 15th post.

Comment: I would add that if you're going to use the same newsletter code elsewhere, make it a template part or something and call it up using that.

Answer (score 2):

here's your working code.

```
<?php 

$i = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if($i % 5 == 0){?>
    <div class="forward">
    SOME NEWSLETTER CODE HERE
    </div>
    <?}
$post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Copy and try. Let me know. Thanks